# How to make customisation drop-down in Rails Admin associations model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

Rails Admin has_many associations option drop customization

I want to make some changes in rails admin select drop-down option. I have some models with has_many relationship.

Model Files
**post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true
    def post_image
       photos&.first&.asset_url
    end
end
```

**photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**homepage.rb**

```
class Homepage < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :homepagepost
    has_many :posts,-> { order(likes_count: :desc) }, through: :homepagepost
end
```

**homepagepost.rb**

```
class Homepagepost < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Rails admin config **rails_admin.rb**

```
config.model Homepage do
    label "Homepage Rows"
    edit do
      field :title_heading
      field :posts
      field :status
    end
    list do
      field :title_heading
      field :posts
      field :status
      field :created_at
      field :updated_at
    end
end
```

Now I want to show post image URL in Post drop-down with the post ID. how I do this in rails admin?
Like **Post #1370 post_test.png**

[image]

**Schema**

```
create_table "photos", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "asset_url"
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_photos_on_post_id"
end

create_table "posts", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.text "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
end 

create_table "homepageposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "homepage_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_homepageposts_on_post_id"
end

create_table "homepages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title_heading"
    t.integer "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First configure on the rails admin initializer, typically on `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` inside the configuration block a method that will be used in your models to determine the title to show for each object like this:

```rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.label_methods = [:rails_admin_title]
end
```

Then on your post model define that method

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: true

    def rails_admin_title
      "<a href='#{post_image}'>Link</a>".html_safe
    end

    def post_image
      photos&.first&.asset_url
    end
end
```

You might need to restart your development server to see this change.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Have you see post has many photos relationship? how it will work in rails_admin_title?

Comment: Sure it will work, each post instance will have access to the associated photos.first. I updated my answer to include the full model to avoid confusion.

Comment: How I can Show an image or add a link for the image? I need to add a link for the image where the user clicks on the link and open in the new tab or show image in the list option.

Comment: Thats another stackoverflow question i strongly suggest you create it, and i'll be happy to answer there. Otherwise we will derail this.

Comment: Can you please update your answer for show image or add a link in the list. It will save my day. Thank you @guillermo-siliceo-trueba

Comment: Sure, is something like the new rails_admin_title method, you can render any string into html by adding the .html_safe method to the return string

Comment: It's showing HTML in the drop-down list. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4008836/2ebcb21d655f739f7b6bce88920db25a

Comment: This got out of hand, could you create another question for that, because its going to be a little more complicated than what i've shown, you have to implement your own field, and my answer is not the place for that.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba - How should we define the `posts` field in the `rails_admin` file if we want only those `posts` which has `status` as `approved` ?

Comment: Could you add another question for that? If you tag it rails-admin I'll get a notification and I'll help you there.